# Alert shown in onActivityResult

Tags: android

I am trying to show custom alert from onActivityResult. I need to inflate it, so am getting context with `getApplicationContext()` and everything is fine until I execute `alertDialog.show()` - then it fails with:

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Do you know why I cannot do it?

(it happens on 1.6 and 2.0 - I didn't test others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the sollution! 
This thread was very helpful: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg17294.html

I was doing:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
...
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Instead of:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```